# Does someone have a working example of Netsuite PHPtoolkit v. 2013_2?

Tags: php, netsuite

I have been searching for days for a working example! The Netsuite documentation is really poor. I don't know what exactly are the config parameters or where I can get them. 
I'm recreating the `get_customer` example.

**My code:**

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';


$service = new NetSuiteService();

$request = new GetRequest();
$request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
$request->baseRef->internalId = "21";
$request->baseRef->type = "customer";
$getResponse = $service->get($request);

if (!$getResponse->readResponse->status->isSuccess) {
    echo "GET ERROR";
} else {
    $customer = $getResponse->readResponse->record;
    echo "GET SUCCESS, customer:";
    echo "\nCompany name: ". $customer->companyName;
    echo "\nInternal Id: ". $customer->internalId;
    echo "\nEmail: ". $customer->email;
}

?>
```

**This is the thrown error:**

```
Webservice host must be specified in NSPHPClient->__construct()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, there should be a file in the same directory as NetSuiteService.php called NSconfig.php. You don't need to include this file in your script; it gets called from NSPHPClient.php. The default NSconfig.php looks like this:

```
$nsendpoint = "2013_2";
$nshost = "https://webservices.netsuite.com";

$nsemail = "jDoe@netsuite.com";
$nspassword = "mySecretPwd";
$nsrole = "3";
$nsaccount = "MYACCT1";
```

The nsendpoint and nshost should stay as they are.

The tricky part is getting the correct settings for the other variables. First off, you need to Set up Web Services (http://www.netsuite.com/portal/partners/integration/download/SuiteTalkWebServicesPlatformGuide_2012.2.pdf Starting at **page 34**), then you need to create a Web Services Role (**page 44**), and make sure that Role has the necessary permissions. Assign that Role to a user that also has the appropriate permissions, then...

**nsemail** = the email of the user with the web services role

**nspassword** = the password of the nsemail user

**nsrole** = the internal role id of the web services role

**nsaccount** = your netsuite account number (most likely six digits)

*(for info on seeing your internal role ids, see **page 20** of the PDF above.)*

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have included the **NSconfig.php** file. Also you need to modify this file with your account credentials